# Powershell POST to Linux curl

Tags: linux, powershell, curl

I have a Powershell script which uses REST API POST and calls one of the sites:

```
$Url='http://11111111111'
$Body='<input xmlns="http://www.123body123body.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
$ContentType='application/xml'

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "passwordnew" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("admin", $secpasswd)

Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -Uri $url -Credential $Cred -ContentType $ContentType -Body $Body -TimeoutSec 12000
```

However we are moving to linux server but I am not able to install powershell.

I tried to rewrite this to linux equivalent (which is `curl` ?), but
it's not working. This is what I've got so far:

```
curl --user "admin" --header "Content-Type: application/xml" --request POST --body '<input xmlns="http://www.123body123body.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' http://11111111111
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Will it be possible for you to use powershell-core in the linux machine ? (might save you some time as you don't have to convert all your ps scripts  )

Comment: What happens when you run your `curl` command? Any return or error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried recreating the request in Postman? The result I get when I do that is as following:

```
 curl -X POST \
  http://11111111111/ \
  -H 'authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmRuZXc=' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/xml' \
  -H 'postman-token: 2963c938-3a5a-0f67-4701-b452a6c5f0ab' \
  -d '<input xmlns="http://www.123body123body.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
```

Note the 'postman-token' in the header, which is generated by the basic authentication with username 'admin' and password 'passwordnew'.

Hope this helps